# when should assign responsibility to service instead of entity object?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Is there any rule of thumb that when should assign responsibility to service object instead of entity object?  I really get confused about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that there's no rule of thumb here. Working out the responsibilities of classes is the skill in designing OO software.

That said, your class design should give you some hints. For example, if you had planned to create a method as part of an entity but that method needs data that's not part of the entity, that would suggest the method is operating on a level above the entity, potentially a domain service.

Comment: I need some Guidance like what you mentioned: "if you had planned to create a method as part of an entity but that method needs data that's not part of the entity, that would suggest the method is operating on a level above the entity, potentially a domain service." thanks for that.

Comment: @mohsenkw You should read the blue book or the DDD Quickly version. It's all explained in there. The textbook example is `TransferFunds()` not belonging to source or destination `Account` but to a `FundsTransferService` class.

Comment: Also, Vaughn Vernon's recent book is excellent. When you break it down, using DDD, you either have an Entity, a Value, an Aggregate, a Factory, a Repository or a Service. A process of elimination, in terms of what the class isn't can help to work out its role.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know about domain driven design, entity objects are the representation of some complex data. Most probably they do not have any business logic around it.

So if you are thinking about the responsibility of just data holding then it would go in Entity Object. Service Objects are the one who would own the responsibility of complex logic on given Value or Entity object with provided context.

Answer (score 0):

Use domain services when you need to operate on multiple aggrigate roots.